# Instagram api profile/users

Tags: api, instagram

I see this sites iconosquare/websta and they already have all users/tags appearing in google results, how can this be done where are they getting a list of all users to put in their own database?

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Iconosquare uses the Instagram API to get user info, using a system they call endpoints. You can request the user ID using the API, and this pulls the information out of the database and transfers it into Iconosquare. You use Get to get that info. It limits the scope to what's public if the user ID requested is not your user ID.

Here's more info about the API: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/

Now that Iconosquare is behind a paywall, you might want to look for alternatives. You can access the API yourself with a token or try a paid service like Crowdbabble.